# How to overwrite a bd file

Tags: java, android

There is such task: from the server to receive a file of a database (in a format.db) and to overwrite an old file on new.

I try so:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers,
                                      File file) {
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getText(R.string.error),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "response - success - " + file);

    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        String outputFile = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("name_db"));
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
        int i;
        while ((i = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
             output.write(buffer, 0, i);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pd.cancel();
}
```

But it does not work. What is the best way to implement this?

Just in case, the code to send the file to the server:

```
 RequestParams params_ = new RequestParams();
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);

 Context context = getApplicationContext();

 File dbFile = new File(String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("name_db")));

 try {
      params_.put("db", dbFile);
 } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      Log.v(TAG, "error - file not found");
 }

 client.post("example.com", params_, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, JSONObject json) {
             Log.v(TAG, "response -- " + json);
             try {
                  if (0 == json.getInt("status")) {
                      Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getText(R.string.successfully),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getText(R.string.error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              pd.cancel();
         }
   });
```

Comment: I'd try first to move the old to temporary location, then write the new one and if the new written successfully delete the old one.

Comment: @RobertNavado, I have not yet learned how to work with files.
How it will be more correct?

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/

Comment: @RobertNavado, I try this way: `File aFile = file;String path = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("targets_db")) + ".db"; if (aFile.renameTo(new File(path))) {Log.v(TAG, "File is moved successful!");}` In the console, I see that "the file was moved successfully!", But the database was not updated.

Comment: Do you refresh your database object after updating the file?

Comment: Or how do you know it's not updated?

Comment: @RobertNavado, After I receive the database from the server and overwrite the file, either the data should appear or be deleted. The principle of backup. I made a backup -> backup went to the server -> I download backup from the server, and the database is not restored to the required state.